# Searching a directory for files

Tags: linux, csh

Hi all I am trying to write a script which recursively searches directories from a parent directory and counts how many text files (.txt) are in the sub directories. I also need to output the files relative path to the parent directory.

Lets say I have a folder named Files

Within this folder there may be:

```
Files/childFolder1/child1.txt
Files/childFolder1/child2.txt
Files/childFolder1/child3.txt
Files/childFolder2/child4.txt
Files/childFolder2/child5.txt
Files/child6.txt
```

So the output would be

```
The files are:

/childFolder1/child1.txt
/childFolder1/child2.txt
/childFolder1/child3.txt
/childFolder2/child4.txt
/childFolder2/child5.txt
/child6.txt

There are 6 files in the 'Files' folder
```

So far I have a script which is this:

```
#! /bin/csh

find $argv[1] -iname '*.txt'

set wc=`find $argv[1] -iname '*.txt' | wc -l`

echo "Number of files under" $argv[1] "is" $wc
```

I have no idea how to make the output so it only shows the file path relative to the directory. Currently my output is something like this:

```
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/childFolder1/child1.txt
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/childFolder1/child2.txt
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/childFolder1/child3.txt
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/childFolder2/child4.txt
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/childFolder2/child5.txt
/home/Alice/Documents/Files/child6.txt
Number of files under /home/Alice/Documents/Files is 6
```

Which is not desired. I am also worried about how I am setting the `$wc` variable. If the directory listing is large then this is going to acquire a massive overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find $argv[1] -iname '*.txt' -printf "%P \n"
```

This should give the desired output :)

Hayden

Answer (score 1):

`cd $argv[1]` first and then use `find . -iname '*.txt'` to make the results relative to the directory

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to execute *find* twice, you can either:

- store its output in a variable, though I don't know if variables are limited in size in csh ;
- store its output in a temporary file, but purists don't like temporary file;
- count the number of lines yourself in a *while* loop which iterates over the results of find.

Note that if you used bash instead, which supports *process substitution* you could duplicate *find*'s output and pipe it to multiple commands with *tee*:

```
find [...] | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2) >/dev/null
```